# Use express js to pass form data to new page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm still fairly new to Express.js. I have a question about sending form data to an existing template. I have two routes which have template views associated with them. One page has a form on it and I want to take inputs from that form to populate the other template of the other route. I'm using Hanglebars for my template engine.

I've found a lot of helpful answers here (this one especially [Cannot POST form node.js - express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902923/cannot-post-form-node-js-express) ), but none that quite answer my question.

I know how to post to create a new page with the form data. Like this:

```
router.post('/game', function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.body.username);
});
```

But how do I get `req.body.username` accessible to a handlebars template? I've been reading various tutorials and it looks like I need to do something with next() in `app.use('/game', game);`. But I'm getting lost as to what exactly that is.

Here's a simplified version of my code.

My main server file:

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var path = require('path');
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var game = require('./routes/game');

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/game', game);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

My route file "index.js":

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
      title: 'Pick a Player',
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the form on index.handlebars (just the form):

```
<form method="post" action="/game" novalidate name="pick-a-player" id="pickAPlayer" class="form-box">
 <p>What is your name?</p>
 <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="name">
 <p>Please select a player</p>
 <label>
     <input type="radio" name="player" value="Jane" checked> Jane<br>
     <input type="radio" name="player" value="Sue"> Sue<br>
     <input type="radio" name="player" value="Anne"> Anne<br>
 </label>
 <input type="submit" value="Start the game" id="submitCharacterForm">
</form>
```

I know I need to use post to get the data through req.body. But I'm getting the template through .get(). How do get the two to communicate?

Here's the route for game.js

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

/* GET Game page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('game', {
      title: 'Let's Play',
      username: req.body.username,
      player: req.body.player
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

When the value of player gets called on game.handlebars, it looks like this:

```
<p class="player-card">{{player}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, the main form will have two values on the request body: `username` and `player`.

This form will make a `POST` request to `/game` according to your form block:

```
<form method="post" action="/game" ...>
```

You handle this `POST` request with the following route handler:

```
router.post('/game', function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.body.username);
});
```

And you want to send the `username` and `player` values to your `game` template correct?

If I'm understanding this correctly, you can either [`res.redirect` with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035373/how-do-i-redirect-in-expressjs-while-passing-some-context) or simply render a different view with the data:

```
router.post('/game', (req, res) => {
  const { username, player } = req.body
  res.render('play-game', { username, player });
});
```

Comment: This solved the problem thank you! The only difference was my express did not like the "=>" and it erred at the point until I removed it.

Comment: I used [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), but if this answer was correct then please accept for future readers.

Comment: Ah forgot to remove function from my version to use the arrow function. Now it works