# 404 Cannot Post using Express & hbs

Tags: node.js, express

Node Express (4.16) + Multer (3.2.3), was able to upload a photo. Now want to display some dynamic message after receiving upload, so I tried [hbs](https://github.com/pillarjs/hbs) (not Express-Handlbars or Express-hbs), template prompts for file ok, but always got

[image]

app structure

[image]

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser= require('body-parser')
var path = require('path');
const app = express();
const multer = require('multer');
fs = require('fs-extra');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
var index = require("./route/index");
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.use('/', index);
app.post('*', index);
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const r = express.Router();
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const multer = require('multer');
fs = require('fs-extra');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads')         // uploads = name of the destination folder
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/', upload.single('picture'), (req, res) => {
    var img = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
});

r.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index');
});
app.post('/', upload.single('picture'), (req, res) => {
    var img = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
    });

app.post('/uploadphoto', upload.single('picture'), (req, res) => {
  var i = 1;
  ...
});

module.exports = r;
```

**index.hbs**

```
<form action="/uploadphoto" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"> 
  Single Img.
  <input type="file" name="picture" accept="image/*" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload an Image"/>
</form>
<h2>{{dynamicHere}}</h2>
```

Already checked other SO including [Cannot POST / error using express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931135/cannot-post-error-using-express), and [Cannot POST form node.js - express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902923/cannot-post-form-node-js-express)

Fiddler shows no more than status 404 and "Cannot post". Does not hit any breakpoint in VSC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exporting `r`, Which contains only one route `r.get('/', function(req, res){})`. To use `/uploadphoto` you need to export `app`

```
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: I thought exports would export the whole file