# Cannot POST /Compnent Name , getting 404 in Network Tab when redirecting from Third Party App

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
App.js

    <PgRequest />   
    <BrowserRouter> 
        <Route exact path="/PgResponse" component={PgResponse}/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**PgRequestComponent**

```
class PgRequest extends Component{

ComponentDidMount()
{
this.submitForm();
}

submitForm=()=>{
document.form[0].method='post';
document.form[0].action='http://xxxxxx/tp/Pg';
document.form[0].submit();
}

render(){
return(
<div>
<form>
<input type='text' name='Name' />
<input type='text' name='ReturnUrl' value='http://localhost:3000/PgResponse' />
</form>
</div>
)
}
}
```

Now When Successfully Form Submitted to "http://xxxxxx/tp/Pg" then It redirects to my URL "localhost:3000/PgResponse"

Getting "**Cannot POST /ComponentName**"

in Network tab it shows 404 not Found but when i type URL in Browser it redirects me to that component i know its Get call when i type URL 
but  how can i solve this so that it redirects to my component from Third party

Response from third Party: Screenshot

[Return to my Component but Getting 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qk9pB.png)

Comment: When you are using BrowserRouter and you wish to navigate using url either directly or from a 3rd party app, you need to configure your server to return the home page of your app for all routes and then the client can perform the routing itself. You can refer this article for nodejs or webpack dev server: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/

Comment: i read article but still failed while i use <HashRouter> as Suggested for server side Routing.

Comment: I think your server can't handle POST method on `/PgResponse` endpoint, It's not a reactjs error, It look like a nodejs error. You can find more information here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/14902923/9150452